# Converting an epoch to UTC in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, time, plsql, timestamp, timezone

What's the best way to convert an epoch column to UTC in the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss` in Oracle db (PL/SQL).

e.g. `1646670198000` --> `2022-03-07 4:23:18`

Comment: A `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` is a binary data type (and so is a `DATE`) and it is never stored with a particular format. If you want to format a timestamp then that is a display problem and not a storage problem.

Answer (score 1):

The main consideration is the **data type** of the result. Epoch is a timestamp at time zone GMT; the data type **should** be `timestamp with time zone`.

If we can agree on this, then here's one way:

```
select timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT' 
         + 1646670198 * interval '1' second as ts
from   dual
;



TS                          
----------------------------
2022-03-07 16:23:18.000 GMT
```

I wrote it that way - with the epoch set off separately as a multiplying factor - so that you can replace it with a column name, a bind variable, or any other expression that evaluates to a valid epoch in seconds.